# how set mod_rewrite by ip all pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i use friendly url names like myservice/controller/action/key/value/key/value etc. Everything is ok when i am running my server on remote hosting. But now i tried run server on my linux and i have a access by ip. My mod_rewrite rules doesn't work. Could someone tell me how can i change this ?

my old rules working on remote hosting with domain

```
rewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
```

And this is my new rules not working

```
rewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.104$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: after click on link on site should be go to: http://192.168.1.104/stats/info but is The requested URL /stats/info was not found on this server.

Comment: seems it should be `%{SERVER_ADDR}` or `%{HTTP_HOST}` since the `REMOTE_ADDR` is a client IP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i tried many times and this rules works fine

```
rewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
```

But in vhost in apache2/available-sites i had to add

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thanx for help